# Trouble catching exception on Azure Service Bus SendAsync method

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm trying to use the following code to setup a failure condition, namely were there is no network path available, so the code shouldn't be able to send to the Service bus at all. I know this because I disable my network ports when I test.

I am still having trouble with the Async nature of the code though. I don't know in a console application like I have how to attach something that would log out the exception that I know should be generated.

How do I see that exception text?

```
        public async Task TestQueueExists()
    {    
        _queueClient = new QueueClient(AppSettings.McasServiceBusConnectionString,
            AppSettings.ListServSyncQueueName);
        Logger.Information(
            $"Queue Created to: {_queueClient.QueueName} with RecieveMode: {_queueClient.ReceiveMode}");
        try
        {
            await _queueClient.SendAsync(new Message("Test".ToUtf8Bytes()));       
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and write to a log file

Comment: Okay, can you elaborate? I am not familar with that style of getting expcetions.

Comment: Try-catch around awaited code should work just fine

Comment: my guess is that the program crashed right after that's why you are not seeing the exception. if you want your program to crash when that exception happens then write to a file instead

Comment: With @Steve on this one. Log file is much better for investigation than console output.

Comment: Yeah I do log it, but I can't seem to catch anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I ran into was that I was using a Console application and the Console app runs sync out of the box.  I had to modify my `Main` to return a `Task` and use `async` for the exception to be caught, which makes sense.

ie

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
         [..]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I assumed that you are using the Azure Service Bus .NET Standard client library [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/). Per my test, you could leverage the following code to capture the exception as follows:

```
try
{
    await _queueClient
        .SendAsync(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world")))
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Status + "," + t.IsFaulted + "," + t.Exception.InnerException);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

If the network is break, you may capture the exception as follows:

[image]

Comment: It worked but I just wonder if the statement within ContinueWith will be executed or not if the user closes the application immediately after SendAsync? Usually SendAsync will take a little bit of time to fail.

Comment: This did not work for me.  Console app is quitting with status 0.  try/catch isn't catching anything; this ContinueWith approach isn't catching anything.  something is nuking the app and nuking it HARD